# django rest framework combination of write_only=True and required=False not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my serializer based on Django Rest Framework serializers.ModelSerializer
I am declaring field, which will be only considered during importing some data (deserialization) and which is not reflecting any model field.

```
new_number = serializers.CharField(
    write_only=True, required=False,
    allow_null=True, default=''
)
```

From [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments):

```
write_only
```

> Set this to True to ensure that the field may be used when updating or
>   creating an instance, but is not included when serializing the
>   representation.
>
> Defaults to False

```
required
```

> Normally an error will be raised if a field is not supplied during
>   deserialization. Set to false if this field is not required to be
>   present during deserialization.
>
> Setting this to False also allows the object attribute or dictionary
>   key to be omitted from output when serializing the instance. If the
>   key is not present it will simply not be included in the output
>   representation.
>
> Defaults to True.

The problem I ancounter is that when this field is empty, I get error: 
`{'new_number': ['This field can not be blank']}`

I am running:

```
djangorestframework==3.2.3
Django==1.8.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **pass `allow_blank=True` argument in the `new_number` serializer field.** Its default value is `False`.

```
new_number = serializers.CharField(
    write_only=True, required=False, allow_blank=True, # allow empty string as a valid value
    default=''
)
```

From the [`allow_blank`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) argument documentation:

> allow_blank - If set to `True` then the empty string should be
>   considered a valid value. If set to `False` then the empty string is
>   considered invalid and will raise a validation error. Defaults to
>   `False`.

Also, you should use `allow_blank` instead of `allow_null` here and not both because as this will mean there will be 2 types of empty value possible.

> The `allow_null` option is also available for string fields, although
>   **its usage is discouraged in favor of `allow_blank`**. It is valid to set
>   both `allow_blank=True` and `allow_null=True`, but doing so means that
>   there will be two differing types of empty value permissible for
>   string representations, which can lead to data inconsistencies and
>   subtle application bugs.